# Creating a Dynamic PDF and Saving it in a folder using Loop with MYSQL and Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

This is the public function with looping (Edited)

public function generate_salary_slip(){

```
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');  
    $data = [];
    $slip = $this->Admin_Login_Model->generate_salary_slip();
    //$html = array();
    $html='';
    if(!empty($slip)){
        foreach($slip as $slip_list){               
            $id = $slip_list->emp_id;
            $data['attendance'] = $this->Admin_Login_Model->get_slip_attendance($id);
            $data['emp_profile'] = $this->Admin_Login_Model->get_emp_details($id);
            $data['late_day'] = $this->Admin_Login_Model->get_late_days($id);
            $data['half_days'] = $this->Admin_Login_Model->get_half_days($id);
            $data['salary'] = $this->Admin_Login_Model->get_salary_slip($id);               
            $data['second_half'] = $this->Admin_Login_Model->get_half_Second_days($id);             
            //$html=$this->load->view('admin/payslip',$data);
            $pdfFilePath = date("F_Y")."salary_slip.pdf";
            $html .= $this->load->view('admin/payslip', $data, true);
        }
        $htmlval = $html;
        //echo $html;exit;
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($htmlval);
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output('salary_slips/'.$pdfFilePath, "F");


        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Salary slips saved in directory!');
        redirect('admin_attendance_list');
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Salary slips not available for this month!');
        redirect('admin_attendance_list');
    }
}
```

File is getting saved in the folder, but Only with the First Record. Also, Repeated loop is getting generated, but with same record.

How to create a HTML by loop.

**PS: Using MPDF to generate PDF File**

Any hep will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the render, writeHtml and Output calls outside the forech loop, there is you problem.

You could save all the data in a var and then render the HTML as you are doing now and then generate the PDF.

EDIT: Your code should look something like this (please read comments below):

```
$htmlData = array();
if(!empty($slip)){
    foreach ($slip as $slip_list) {
        // 
        $htmlData[] = $data;
    }

    $pdfFilePath = date("F_Y")."salary_slip.pdf";
    $html = $this->load->view('admin/payslip', $htmlData, true);
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output('salary_slips/'.$pdfFilePath, "F");
```

Comment: As per your suggestion made necessary changes as below.
foreach($slip as $slip_list){       
 //$html=$this->load->view('admin/payslip',$data);
 $pdfFilePath = date("F_Y")."salary_slip.pdf";
 $html = $this->load->view('admin/payslip', $data, true);
}
 $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
 $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output('salary_slips/'.$pdfFilePath, "F");
It is Creating a Loop but only Last Record

Comment: And how did it go?

Comment: How to use Render in MPDF..?

Comment: I meant render the html view using CodeIgniter, like you are already doing: $html = $this->load->view(...)

Comment: I cannot understand the code if you put it in a comment as it's not formatted. You can consider adding it to your question as an edition so it's clear to read.

Comment: Did that, but getting last record only as an output.. Not All record.

Comment: You are overwriting the $html var in every loop, you need to save the necessary data in a var and then pass it to the view outside the loop (aka render). In other words, you need to call $this->load->view only once after the loop and pass the collected data.

Comment: Sir, Updated the Code.. Kindly check. The HTML Records are getting generated but when converting to PDF, it generates only the First.

Comment: Do not call $this->load->view inside the loop, do it outside before calling $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML

Comment: @user4386169 I updated my answer, please see there the changes I made to your code.

Comment: Hi, were you able to perform this?